# Ubuntu settings say "No Bluetooth Found" even though I have a device connected and working well

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, system-settings

First, my issue is slightly different than usual issues with Bluetooth on linux. Let me state this clear - **my Bluetooth connection DOES work**.

I'm listening music via Bluetooth connected headphones right now. Even though *Bluetooth* section of *Ubuntu System Settings* looks like this:

[image]

This is quite annoying, any idea how to fix it?

It's Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, kernel (manually updated) 4.10.0-38.

For comparison, below a few other places on the same Ubuntu instance having contrary idea of the bluetooth status.

***System Settings - Sound***

[image]
(highlighted device is the Bluetooth headphones)

**Bluetooth indicator**

[image]

So why does it say *Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth* at the settings panel?